# How to schedule PostgreSql procedure using Heroku scheduler?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to schedule PostgreSql procedure using Heroku scheduler. I tried heroku pg:psql -c "call procedure_name();" --app app-name but gets the error from scheduler "bash: heroku: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is telling you important information. The Heroku CLI is not present in your environment, so `bash` complains that `heroku` isn't a command that it recognizes.

If you want to run `heroku` commands from your application you'll need to include the [cli buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli) when you build your application to make sure it's properly bundled. Once you've included the buildpack and triggered a new build, this should work.